# SharePoint online - workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I am working on a workflow in SharePoint online using MS flow. My workflow has multiple conditions.

My issue is the that **I don't see the workflows running in the history section**.

The workflow check for a yes and no value, if the value is no sends an email but if it's yes it moves to next condition which it checks for a yes or no value, pretty much the same process for each step. I have at least 2 of the 6 working but I don't know what else to do to fix it. Everything is pretty much the same with exception of the field name.

Any help on a flow with multiple criteria?

[image: Workflow with Multiple Conditions]

Comment: Can you post your flow and point where you are having an issue?

Comment: Hi @user156238, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti I've added an screenshot of my workflow.

Comment: Can you explain further **I have at least 2 of the 6 working but I don't know what else to do to fix it** on this statement?

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti The workflow works based on the list that have 6 yes/no options. The idea is to send an email to the team that is pending their actions. We know if their action is pending is the value of their team is set to "No" in the switch. When the DB_Team changes his No, to Yes, the Server_Team gets an email saying that is something pending for them to do. When the Server_Team changes his to Yes, nothing else happens. What is should happen

Comment: the workflow should check DB_Team =Yes, move to next condition, which is Server_Team=Yes, and move to Backup_Team=No, which it suppose to send an email to Backup_Team.. so DB_Team is working fine with both options, ( email sent because DB_Team=No, and move to next condition when DB_Team=Yes) Server_Team works for the email when is NO, but doesn't move the flow when is set to YES. Does this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what your Flow does, it should show each run in the Flow History.  If your Flow is not working correctly, I would still expect it to appear with a "Failed" status:

[image]

If it truly is not showing each run, then you should confirm if the Flow trigger is targeting the correct list or library.  It might be the case that your trigger is looking at a different SharePoint list or library from the one you expect.

[image]